# add variable to name label in C#

Tags: c#, oop, variables, object

```
int j = 1;
        label+j.Text = "";
```

after variable to name label show error

```
Error   1   The name 'label' does not exist in the current context
```

how to use this in C#?

Answer (score 1):

With [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) method you can get any control by it's name in runtime:

```
Label lbl = this.Controls.Find("label"+j, true).FirstOrDefault() as Label;
lbl.text = "";
```

It returns a collection of all possible controls, but we need only one (first), if it's name is unique.

Answer (score 0):

If your control name is `label` then you probably want to do like

```
    this.label.Text = string.Empty;
```